# Crosstab Report With Dynamic Columns in PRD

Tags: report, pentaho

i want to create a crosstab report in PRD but with dynamic columns based on report filter

For example i want to generate summary purchase report based on selected date

Sample of table :

```
Date    Purchase No Total Value
1-Jan   PO001    $10.00 
5-Jan   PO002    $20.00 
7-Jan   PO003    $30.00 
7-Jan   PO004    $40.00 
20-Jan  PO005    $50.00 
22-Jan  PO006    $60.00 
22-Jan  PO007    $70.00 
25-Jan  PO008    $10.00 
30-Jan  PO009    $20.00
```

So if my filter is from 1 Jan to 15 Jan then my report should looks like this:

```
Description              1-Jan      5-Jan      7-Jan
Purchase total value     $10.00      $20.00      $70.00
```

Then if my filter is from 1 Jan to 30 Jan it will looks like :

```
Description              1-Jan      5-Jan      7-Jan      20-Jan     22-Jan     25-Jan    30-Jan
Purchase total value     $10.00      $20.00      $70.00      $50.00      $130.00     $10.00      $20.00
```

Any idea how to create this on PRD ?
currently i have PRD 3.9 & 5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, refer to link below
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o_J3nkFRgpI

But crosstab can only works well in version 4.0 above.
I tried on my version 3.9 it doesn't work well. The aggregation is not working.